# Where is private_key on Ubuntu?

Tags: web-hosting, private-key

I am trying to change the RSA private key for my website. I have heard you have to edit `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/private_key`, but that isn't a file. Here's the output of `ls /var/lib/tor/hidden_service`:

```
authorized_clients  hostname  hs_ed25519_public_key  hs_ed25519_secret_key
```

I tried editing `hs_ed25519_secret_key` but it shows weird symbols, probably because of its encoding. So where is `private_key`?

Answer (score 0):

The private key of your Onion service is `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hs_ed25519_secret_key`. It uses [Ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Ed25519) as signature scheme and *not* RSA. Furthermore it is also not possible to edit the file directly.

If you want to change the key, you can stop your Tor process, delete the files inside `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service` and restart Tor. The software will then create new keys and a new hostname for you.